# CommonDomain/EventStore/CQRS : Where is the test project for commondomain?

Tags: cqrs, neventstore, commondomain

I have downloaded CommonDomain from GitHub and I can see a directory

```
/ src / tests / CommonDomain.AcceptanceTests
```

which contains the file "When_an_aggregate_is_persisted.cs" but there is no project that uses it. Also the base class "in_the_event_store" seems to be missing. There are also references to FakeBus, IDomainEvent, SynchronousDispatcher etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CommonDomain is not under any kind of test.  There are some old files that were under some kind of test at one point but the test files were removed from the solution at one point.  The CommonDomain project was originally spike code (proof of concept) that worked a little bit too well and made it into production.  Interestingly enough, there are actually quite a few users that use it now because it's extremely lightweight and tries to be as unobtrusive as possible.

The future of this project is to merge its essence into the EventStore project because the are two sides of the same coin.  But the new iteration will be under a full suite of tests.

Comment: Would it be able to get access to the removed files? The reason i ask is I was hoping to learn how event-store works and the commonDomain test files seemed to address that. Without them I am worried I might struggle to use event-store in my project. Are there any project on the web that show event-store used with a DDD project?

Comment: Currently I am looking at Mark Nijhof's CQRS project to get an idea how to model the my domain and use event sourcing. I was hoping that I could then swap out his event-store for yours. Not sure if this would work?

Comment: Probably, it's been a while since I've looked at his stuff.

Comment: Any ETA on this conversion? :D

Comment: None yet. I've got a few other higher priorities stacked up.